# How i can read kafka offset per partition

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I can't for-loop read kafka per partition, I don't know what wrong in my code, it don't show the value that I print

example: i want to firsttime read all offset partition 0 and second read all offset partition 1.

(Firsttime for me post in stackoverflow. Sorry for commucation, I hope you understand me.)

```
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(topicNames);
    List<KafkaTopicDataResponse> results = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        Set<TopicPartition> assignments = consumer.assignment();
        Object[] assignArray = assignments.toArray();
        for (Object topicPartition : assignArray){
            boolean flag = true;
            int receiveRow = 0;
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                if (flag) {
                    consumer.seek((TopicPartition) topicPartition,0);
                    flag = false;
                }
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    receiveRow++;
                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, partition = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.partition(), record.key(), record.value());
                    logger.info("count : "+ receiveRow);

                }
                if (receiveRow >= limitRow){
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occured while consuing messages",e);
    }finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
```

Comment: When you do `consumer.poll()` you get messages from all the partitions assigned to that consumer and not just a single partition.

Comment: Is there a specific use-case for reading each partition separately?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes, i want  reading each partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to firsttime read all offset partition 0 and second read all
>   offset partition 1.

You said, you want to read all offsets from partition 0 and then partition 1. How do you say *all* when the data is flowing i.e. new data keeps on arriving?

So when you say *all* it should be *all data at a given instant of time*. For this, you would need to assign the partitions one by one, get the end offsets at that *instant of time* and read them till that end offset.

```
consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(new TopicPartition("topic", 0)));
```

and then you need to fetch the end offsets, because if data keeps on coming to this partition, this partition would never complete.

```
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic", 0);
long endOffset = consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singletonList(tp)).get(tp);
```

Now, you have to call `poll()` and check if the last record is `>= endOffset-1`

```
flag = true;
while(flag) {
       ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
       for(ConsumerRecord record: records) {
          // process them
          if(record.offset() >= (endOffset-1)) {
             flag = false;
             break;   
          }
       }
}
```

Repeat the same steps with other partitions also.